# Is it possible to drag and drop polygon blocks with the mouse?

Tags: lua, drag-and-drop, polygon, love2d

I am practicing simple lua programming with love2d.
What about the code that enables mouse drag and drop of polygon blocks here?

```
function love.load()
    b1 = {}
    mouse = {}

    love.physics.setMeter(70)

    world = love.physics.newWorld(0, 9.81*64, true)
  
    objects = {}
  
    objects.ground = {}
    objects.ground.body = love.physics.newBody(world, 700/2, 660)
    objects.ground.shape = love.physics.newRectangleShape(650, 50)
    objects.ground.fixture = love.physics.newFixture(objects.ground.body,objects.ground.shape)

    objects.lwall = {}
    objects.lwall.body = love.physics.newBody(world, 0, 350)
    objects.lwall.shape = love.physics.newRectangleShape(50, 6500)
    objects.lwall.fixture = love.physics.newFixture(objects.lwall.body,objects.lwall.shape)

    objects.rwall = {}
    objects.rwall.body = love.physics.newBody(world, 700, 350)
    objects.rwall.shape = love.physics.newRectangleShape(50, 6500)
    objects.rwall.fixture = love.physics.newFixture(objects.rwall.body,objects.rwall.shape)

    objects.block1 = {}
    objects.block1.body = love.physics.newBody(world, 200, 300, "dynamic")
    objects.block1.shape = love.physics.newRectangleShape(0, 0, 162.5,32.5)
    objects.block1.fixture = love.physics.newFixture(objects.block1.body, objects.block1.shape, 5)
    
    objects.block2 = {}
    objects.block2.body = love.physics.newBody(world, 200, 350, "dynamic")
    objects.block2.shape = love.physics.newRectangleShape(0, 0, 162.5,32.5)
    objects.block2.fixture = love.physics.newFixture(objects.block2.body, objects.block2.shape, 2)

    objects.block3 = {}
    objects.block3.body = love.physics.newBody(world, 200, 400, "dynamic")
    objects.block3.shape = love.physics.newRectangleShape(0, 0, 162.5,32.5)
    objects.block3.fixture = love.physics.newFixture(objects.block3.body, objects.block3.shape, 5)

    objects.block4 = {}
    objects.block4.body = love.physics.newBody(world, 200, 450, "dynamic")
    objects.block4.shape = love.physics.newRectangleShape(0, 0, 162.5,32.5)
    objects.block4.fixture = love.physics.newFixture(objects.block4.body, objects.block4.shape, 5)

    objects.block5 = {}
    objects.block5.body = love.physics.newBody(world, 200, 500, "dynamic")
    objects.block5.shape = love.physics.newRectangleShape(0, 0, 162.5,32.5)
    objects.block5.fixture = love.physics.newFixture(objects.block5.body, objects.block5.shape, 5)

    objects.block6 = {}
    objects.block6.body = love.physics.newBody(world, 200, 550, "dynamic")
    objects.block6.shape = love.physics.newRectangleShape(0, 0, 162.5,32.5)
    objects.block6.fixture = love.physics.newFixture(objects.block6.body, objects.block6.shape, 5)

    objects.block7 = {}
    objects.block7.body = love.physics.newBody(world, 200, 600, "dynamic")
    objects.block7.shape = love.physics.newRectangleShape(0, 0, 162.5,32.5)
    objects.block7.fixture = love.physics.newFixture(objects.block7.body, objects.block7.shape, 5)

    love.graphics.setBackgroundColor(0, 0, 0)
    love.window.setMode(700, 650)
  end
  
function getMouse()
    local isDown = love.mouse.isDown(1,2)
        return x, y, isDown
    end
  
function love.update(dt)
    world:update(dt) 
    mouse.x, mouse.y = love.mouse.getPosition()
    objects.block1.x, objects.block1.y = objects.block1.body:getPosition()

    if love.keyboard.isDown("d") then
        objects.block1.body:applyForce(4000, 0)
        objects.block1.body:applyTorque(100000)
        if love.keyboard.isDown("w") then
            objects.block1.body:applyForce(0, -150000)
            objects.block1.body:setLinearVelocity(0, 0)
        end

        elseif love.keyboard.isDown("a") then
            objects.block1.body:applyForce(-4000, 0) 
            objects.block1.body:applyTorque(-100000)   

            if love.keyboard.isDown("w") then
                objects.block1.body:applyForce(0, -150000)
                objects.block1.body:setLinearVelocity(0, 0)
            end
  
        elseif love.keyboard.isDown("w") then
            objects.block1.body:applyForce(0, -350000)
            objects.block1.body:setLinearVelocity(0, 0)
        
        elseif love.keyboard.isDown("s") then
            objects.block1.body:applyForce(0, 350000)
            objects.block1.body:setLinearVelocity(0, 0)
        end    

        if love.keyboard.isDown("l") then
            objects.block2.body:applyForce(4000, 0)
        
        elseif love.keyboard.isDown("j") then
            objects.block2.body:applyForce(-4000, 0)
  
        elseif love.keyboard.isDown("i") then
            objects.block2.body:applyForce(0, -150000)
            objects.block2.body:setLinearVelocity(0, 0)
        end

        if objects.block1.body:getPosition() == love.mouse.getPosition() then
            if love.mouse.isDown(1) then
                objects.block1.x = objects.block1.x - 700
                objects.block1.y = objects.block1.y - 650 
        end
    end
end
  
function love.draw()
    love.graphics.setColor(0.7, 0.7, 0.7)
    love.graphics.polygon("fill", objects.ground.body:getWorldPoints(objects.ground.shape:getPoints()))
    love.graphics.polygon("fill", objects.lwall.body:getWorldPoints(objects.lwall.shape:getPoints()))
    love.graphics.polygon("fill", objects.rwall.body:getWorldPoints(objects.rwall.shape:getPoints()))
  

    love.graphics.setColor(0.95, 0.5, 0.1)
    love.graphics.polygon("fill", objects.block1.body:getWorldPoints(objects.block1.shape:getPoints()))
    love.graphics.polygon("fill", objects.block2.body:getWorldPoints(objects.block2.shape:getPoints()))
    love.graphics.polygon("fill", objects.block3.body:getWorldPoints(objects.block1.shape:getPoints()))
    love.graphics.polygon("fill", objects.block4.body:getWorldPoints(objects.block2.shape:getPoints()))
    love.graphics.polygon("fill", objects.block5.body:getWorldPoints(objects.block1.shape:getPoints()))
    love.graphics.polygon("fill", objects.block6.body:getWorldPoints(objects.block2.shape:getPoints()))
    love.graphics.polygon("fill", objects.block7.body:getWorldPoints(objects.block1.shape:getPoints()))

    love.graphics.setColor(1, 1, 1)
    love.graphics.print("Mouse locate : " .. mouse.x..','..mouse.y)
    love.graphics.print("block 1 locate : " .. objects.block1.x..','..objects.block1.y, 200)
end
```

How can I fix it so that I can drag and drop each polygon block in that code?
(in a similar way to Google Gravity)

I tried to configure the code so that the individual polygon blocks and the current mouse position are the same, and move when left-clicked, but it failed.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to compare a position (center of object) with the position of the mouse. Both are floats, the chance that you hit exactly the center of your shape is effectively zero.

Instead you might want to check for collision:

```lua
        if love.mouse.isDown(1) then
            local mx, my = love.mouse.getPosition()
            mx, my = objects.block1.body:getLocalPoint(mx, my)
            if objects.block1.shape:testPoint(mx, my, 0, 0, 0) then
                objects.block1.body:setPosition(love.mouse.getPosition())
            end
        end
```

I transformed the current mouse position to the position relative to your body. I then checked, if this point collides with the bodies shape. The last three arguments are not properly documented, but it [looks like](https://github.com/love2d/love/blob/main/src/modules/physics/box2d/Shape.cpp) they are offset and rotation.

I then set the position using the bodies `setPosition`. You tried to set your copy of the position, which won't reflect your change. Notice that setting the position will not reset or modify the velocity, thus if you hold the object, it will still build up velocity due to gravity.

There is still room for improvement, for example, you should hold on the object once pressed, as well as keep the initial offset.